# Uk Residence permit for a non-EEA and what documents to submit

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

I'm from Africa but married to an EEA who lives and works in the UK. I'm about to apply for a residence card as I'm currently in the UK with him on an EEA family permit visa. I would like to know If I have to submit original documents (Marriage certificate, prove of address etc) to the home office apart from my and husband's identification?

Is it advisable to apply with my current address meanwhile before six months I will be moving to a different home with my husband how do I get the new address to the Home office?

Comment: Are you planning to move to the UK or just visit?

Comment: I'm already in the UK and I need to be sure about what documents to submit for a residence permit.